# There is redundant "last login info" in the stdout of fabric.operations.sudo

Tags: python, fabric

When I run the fabric.operations.sudo to get the info from a remote VM (its kernel is 4.14.35 EL7.6), such as "date +%s", the excepted result should be "1549853543", but in my test, it's "Last login: Mon Feb 11 02:53:18 UTC 2019 on pts/0\r\n1549853543".

I have run the command "ssh user@vm 'date +%s'", the result is  normal(only the number).

Does anyone know what's the reason? I have also fixed the "PrintLastLog" to "no" in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

```
 result = sudo('date +%s').stdout.strip()

 run_time = int(result)  => exception occurs
```

Except: 1549853543

Actual: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Last login: Mon Feb 11 02:53:18 UTC 2019 on pts/0\r\n1549853543'

Comment: it happens because you are trying a cast a non-int value(string) into int

Answer (score 0):

Fix the 2 places it seems the last login info disappear:

1. /etc/pam.d/system-auth:

   session     required      pam_lastlog.so silent showfailed

2: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
# Per CCE-CCE-80225-6: Set PrintLastLog yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PrintLastLog no
```